# NoMethodError (undefined method `all' for Admin::Notification:Class)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am getting this error when I am visiting this URL `admin/notifications`

I have moved controller and routes under admin scope

> NoMethodError (undefined method `all' for Admin::Notification:Class)

**Notifications controller**

```
# app/controllers/admin/notifications_controller.rb
module Admin
  class NotificationsController < AdminController
    def index
      @notifications = Notification.all
    end
  end
end
```

**Notification**

```
# app/models/notification.rb
class Notification < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :preferences
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
MyApp::Application.routes.draw do
  namespace :admin do
    resources :notifications
  end
end
```

**Routes**

```
    admin_notifications GET    /admin/notifications(.:format)           admin/notifications#index
                        POST   /admin/notifications(.:format)           admin/notifications#create
 new_admin_notification GET    /admin/notifications/new(.:format)       admin/notifications#new
edit_admin_notification GET    /admin/notifications/:id/edit(.:format)  admin/notifications#edit
     admin_notification GET    /admin/notifications/:id(.:format)       admin/notifications#show
                        PUT    /admin/notifications/:id(.:format)       admin/notifications#update
                        DELETE /admin/notifications/:id(.:format)       admin/notifications#destroy
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `::Notification.all`

It should works.

You are inside Admin module. `Notification.all` is searching for the `Notification`inside module named `Admin`

`::Notification` indicate that `Notification` model is in global Module. So it should get the model and it should solved your error.

Comment: @Deepak Did you test it?